# Distribute force over a rod

Tags: forces, dirac-delta-distributions

Well, the idea is that I have a rod of length $L$ and force $F_0$. Now I have to distribute those $F_0$ Newtons on the rod. But the problem is, that I want to do it continuously. So what I want in the end as a result to this problem is to express force $F(x)$ exerted on the rod at position $x$.

Below I have attached a picture to further explain the problem and avoid any missunderstandings. So if I have a force $F_0$ I can split it into $N$ parts that are not equally big but represent an arbitrary distribution. See graphics.

[image: Force distribution in discrete case scenario.]

In this case the condition says $$\sum_{i=1}^NF_i=F_0.$$ One could also write the force as a function of $x$ like this $$F(x)=\sum_{i=1}^N\lambda _i \delta(x-ia),$$ assuming that the distance between the discretely distributed forces is always constant and equal to $a$. But the problem is increasing $N$ decreases $F_i$. For example if $N\rightarrow 2N$ (which is a step closer to the continuous case I am interested in) yields $F_i\rightarrow F_i/2$ if I want the sum over all $i$ to stay $F_0$. 
In other words the distance $a$ has a huge effect on the size of $F_i$. Take $a$ that is too big and the model is not realistic, take $a$ too small and the $F_i$ approaches zero value. None of which is good.

So, my question to you is... How do I find $F(x)$? Just to clarify I can distribute those $F_0$ over the length $L$ just as I want to. Meaning linear, quadratic, chi squared distribution. I don't care. All I care about is that is normalized to $F_0$. Because $F_0$ is the amount of force I have available. No more, no less.

I tried really hard but I can't figure out how to normalize everything if I assumed quadratic distribution of force over the length $L$. :(

Comment: What about just making your distribution a description of the force density?

Comment: @cag and than demand $\int f(x)dx=F_0$, if $f(x)$ is the force density? How would I than get $F(x)$?

Comment: Hi skrat, welcome to Physics SE! Have you learned any [integral calculus](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/integral-calculus/indefinite-definite-integrals) in your studies? This branch of mathematics deals with exactly this kind of problem; it allows you to break up your 'domain' (the rod, in this case) into infinitely small segments, and to define a function on this domain such that it can be normalised in a rigorous way. There isn't really an easy (general) way to do it in the discrete case illustrated in your diagram.

Comment: @tok3rat0r I have learned integral calculus, yes, but it looks like I don't know how to use any of that knowledge. Sadly. Forget the discrete case - I don't want it. For me it was just the easiest way to explain the problem, since English is not my mother tongue. I am only interested into $F(x)$ being a continuous function.

Comment: @skrat - yes, you've got the right idea. $F(x)$ isn't really meaningful in the case of a general force density $f(x)$. Only by integrating the force per unit length can you get a meaningful, normalised expression which can be solved for $F_0$.

Comment: Of course, you can use integration to find the total force over any finite portion of the rod by restricting the limits of the integral to the range of interest: $F(x,x+a)=\int_{x}^{x+a}f(x')\mathrm{d}x'$ once $f(x)$ is normalised appropriately.

Comment: @tok3rat0r hmmm, true about the fact that one can always restrict the limits of the integral to the range of interest, but doing so you also need a good argument why $a$ is as large as it is. I can set it $a\ll L$ and than $F(x)\rightarrow 0$ or I can say $a\gg L$ and the model is not realistic. The same problems as with the discrete case or am I the only one who sees no difference?

Comment: If you set $a \ll L$ then yes, the total force on that segment will be very small. I don't see this as a problem however; the force will still be finite as long as $a$ is finite. In the opposite limit, you're right that there's no sense in talking about $a>L$. Problems in maths and physics restricted to a finite domain are very common however; again, not really a problem as long as you're careful with the notation.

Comment: _"Problems in maths and physics in which the domain is restricted to a finite range are very common, however; again, not really a problem as long as you're careful with the notation."_ That is exactly the circle I mentioned. Whatever I do I get to this problem. And I have hoped that there is an elegant way around it, but I guess there isn't.